# Why isn't my phone recognized by my computer in Fastboot mode?

Tags: adb, samsung, fastboot

I have recently bought a Samsung Galaxy S42 5G, and was messing around with boot combinations. While I was doing this, I found out that the phone had Download mode, but also a Fastboot mode. I was trying to get this to work with my ADB and FastBoot tools on my computer, but it doesn't seem to be recognized by Fastboot, and in the device manager, my phone shows up as "Android" With a yellow warning mark. Anyone know what is happening?
I can't really find much info on this device.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have came across a fix.
I disabled window's protection against unsigned drivers, and opened google's android drivers, and added my own phones Hardware ID into the list.
I Installed the driver and it's working fine!

Comment: Where do you got the fastboot drivers from? The original Google fastboot drivers that are contained in the Android SDK are signed so no necessity to disable Windows driver signing.